# How to control piTFT backlight in C code?

Tags: gpio, pitft, spi

Controlling the piTFT backlight requires using some basic shell commands, but they don't explain how to do this in C code, and I'm not sure exactly what these commands do (beyond the obvious sudo sh echo to a file).

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi/extras

```
sudo sh -c "echo 252 > /sys/class/gpio/export"
sudo sh -c "echo 'out' > /sys/class/gpio/gpio252/direction"
sudo sh -c "echo '1' > /sys/class/gpio/gpio252/value" (to turn it on, 0 for off)
```

If I understand this correctly, these are not actually GPIO ports on the PI, these commands somehow connect to an IO port on the touchscreen, that is connected over SPI.

I was wondering if somebody could either provide the equivalent in C or (better) explain what is going on here so that I could convert it to C.  What happens in the system when those files are created/modified?  How does the system know that it has to talk to a SPI device and not just enable a Pi GPIO port?

I guess ultimately, I could just use file write commands, but is that really the "right" way to do this or should I be calling some SPI API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those files are part of the kernel [sysfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs).  They are not files on disk, they are nodes in memory and function as a language agnostic [API for using the GPIOs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt); when you read such a file, you are requesting information from the kernel, when you write to one, you are asking it to do something.

So in C you would do something like:

```
int fd = open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY);
write(fd, "252\n", 4);
close(fd);
fd = open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio252", O_WRONLY);
write(fd, "out\n", 5);
close(fd);
```

Obviously wrapping this stuff in something more concise is a good idea.  Note the use of newlines; this is necessary.  I recommend using the low level functions here and not higher level stream based ones.

I have heard of people disturbed by this because of some presumed I/O overhead.  Again, they are not disk files, `open()`/`read()`/`write()` are system calls, you are interfacing with the system, etc.

There is a [more specialized API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/smbus-protocol) for using the I<sup>2</sup>C bus that is C specific, with dedicated function calls.

Although I haven't used it, there's also an [API for SPI](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spidev) which is also based on reading and writing to sysfs nodes, but appears to have a few C `ioctl()` features too.

Note that you can go up levels up in those documentation links to traverse a  tree -- it's mirrored from the kernel source `Documentation/` directory.

Comment: So here's the funny thing, once I added error checking, all of the write calls fail with "Device or resource busy" but they still work (backlight turns on and off).  Ideally I'd prefer not to ignore errors, but I guess I'll have to live with it for now.

Comment: That's a pretty interesting one, lol.  Working with the I2C/smbus API for one particular device made me want to rip out my hair at points -- commands that are described in that doc as "equivalent to" a read()/write() operation ended up not being.  I havn't have this problem though.   Does seem odd.